# Cannot display ggplot in a named chunk when running R Shiny document

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I found that when running a shiny document a regular "un-shiny" ggplot is not able to be displayed **if we name the chunk plotting it** (see code below). I can certainly keep all the "un-shiny" ggplot chunks unnamed, but it will be annoying to code if the shiny document is long and contains a lot of "un-shiny" ggplots.

Thus, I am wondering whether there is a way so that we are able to name all the chunks, regardless of whether it is a shiny or "un-shiny" graph.

Thanks!

````
---
title: ""
author: "" 
date: ""
runtime: shiny
output: 
  html_document:
    fig_height: 3
    fig_width: 6
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse=TRUE, prompt=TRUE, eval=TRUE, message=F,include=T,comment=NULL, echo=TRUE)
```

```{r problematic chunk}
#HAS NAME FOR THIS CHUNK! CANNOT DISPLAY

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(babynames)
head(babynames)

#Let's do male David (and alternative spelling: Dave, Davis, Davi) line plot
babynames %>% filter(name %in% c("David","Dave","Davis","Davi"),sex=="M") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year)) + geom_line(aes(y=n, color=name)) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Count") + ggtitle("Distribution of these four male 'David-like' names over years")
```

```{r}
#NO NAME FOR THIS CHUNK! NO Problem displaying

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(babynames)
head(babynames)

#Let's do male David (and alternative spelling: Dave, Davis, Davi) line plot
babynames %>% filter(name %in% c("David","Dave","Davis","Davi"),sex=="M") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year)) + geom_line(aes(y=n, color=name)) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Count") + ggtitle("Distribution of these four male 'David-like' names over years")
```

```{r Shiny No problem}
library(mosaicData)
head(Galton)

inputPanel(
  checkboxInput("color_or_not",label="Color by sex?",value = FALSE, width = NULL)
)

renderPlot({
  if(input$color_or_not)
  {
    ggplot(Galton,aes(x=father,y=height,color=sex)) + geom_point() + 
      xlab("Father's height") + ylab("Person's height") + ggtitle("Person's height against father's height conditioned on sex")}
  else{
      ggplot(Galton,aes(x=father,y=height)) + geom_point() + 
      xlab("Father's height") + ylab("Person's height") + ggtitle("Person's height against father's height")
  }
})
```
````

Comment: Does it work if you change the chunk name to a string without spaces, e.g., `problematic_chunk`?

Comment: Ah, yes! This indeed works! So now at least we can name it, but it is still a bit annoying since we can only use one string without space in the name?...